# Why is my Me. Reference and INSERT INTO causing error?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am receiving two errors when attempting to create a query which updates my audit log after an update is made to a record.

First I am prompted to enter a Parameter Value where I believed my `ME.` code would point to any record with the current value of field `[Corrected Med Ed ID]`.

Secondly I receive message:

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

My form's code is -

```vb
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    Dim UserName As String

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    'updates date
    DoCmd.RunSQL "update tbl_InterfaceLog SET tbl_InterfaceLog.[LastUpdated] = Date() Where [Corrected Med Ed ID] = " & Me.[Corrected Med Ed ID]
    'stamps username
    DoCmd.RunSQL "update tbl_InterfaceLog SET tbl_InterfaceLog.[LastUpdatedBy] = Username() Where [Corrected Med Ed ID] = " & Me.[Corrected Med Ed ID]
    'Adds the record to log
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl_AuditLog (Status, Comments, Owner, [corrected med ed ID], [Upload File Name], [Submission Method], AirfareStatus, GroundStatus, MealsStatus, AccomodationStatus, AirfareComment, GroundComment, MealsComment, AccommodationComment, Coordinator, SupportRequested, LastUpdated, Reviewed, ReviewerComment, RequiredChange, EventDate, ProductsMatch, SubmissionMethod, TravelDestination, LastUpdatedBy" _
    & " SELECT tbl_InterfaceLog.Status, tbl_InterfaceLog.Comments, tbl_InterfaceLog.Owner, tbl_InterfaceLog.[corrected med ed ID], tbl_InterfaceLog.[Upload File Name], tbl_InterfaceLog.[Submission Method], tbl_InterfaceLog.AirfareStatus, tbl_InterfaceLog.GroundStatus, tbl_InterfaceLog.MealsStatus, tbl_InterfaceLog.AccomodationStatus, tbl_InterfaceLog.AirfareComment, tbl_InterfaceLog.GroundComment, tbl_InterfaceLog.MealsComment, tbl_InterfaceLog.AccommodationComment, tbl_InterfaceLog.Coordinator, tbl_InterfaceLog.SupportRequested, tbl_InterfaceLog.LastUpdated, tbl_InterfaceLog.Reviewed, tbl_InterfaceLog.ReviewerComment, tbl_InterfaceLog.RequiredChange, tbl_InterfaceLog.EventDate, tbl_InterfaceLog.ProductsMatch, tbl_InterfaceLog.SubmissionMethod, tbl_InterfaceLog.TravelDestination, tbl_InterfaceLog.LastUpdatedBy" _
    & " FROM tbl_InterfaceLog" _
    & " WHERE [Corrected Med Ed ID] = " & Me.[Corrected Med Ed ID]
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

Comment: Add a `)` between `LastUpdatedBy` and `SELECT`

Comment: ^ this. Your field list isn't terminated. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: My Me. code is still not functioning. I am prompted to type in the values.

Comment: Double-check the field name spelling for `[Corrected Med Ed ID]`  Any leading or training spaces in the name will be a problem.

Comment: I have checked and the spelling is correct.I have checked, i have tried to rename the field to remove the spaces, nothing is working.

Comment: In that case we can't help you - compare your field list against the table definitions. Since we can't see those, it gets rather hard to put the finger on where the typo is. Consider sticking to `PascalCase` for all table and column names in the future, to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: Does Access ask you for a parameter value for `[Corrected Med Ed ID]` three times when you run the code --- once for each of the three SQL statements?  If not all 3, then which of them trigger the parameter request?

Comment: Is `[Corrected Med Ed ID]` a text or number field?

Comment: Yes it asks 3 times 
I have retyped the name of the fields so all references of field now read [CorrectedMedEdID]

Comment: Is `[Corrected Med Ed ID]` part of the Record Source for your form or the name of a control on your form?

Comment: Create a new query in the Access query designer.  Switch from Design View to SQL View.  Paste in this highlighted text: `SELECT Min([CorrectedMedEdID]) FROM tbl_InterfaceLog`  When you run that query, does Access ask you supply a value for `CorrectedMedEdID`?

Comment: HansUp it returns the correct ID when I do that. I should say that my VBA has been saying Enter Parameter Value and it also has the [CorrectedMedEdID] above where I type the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use parameterized queries and avoid the need to concatenate SQL string in VBA. Specifically, save below two SQL statements as stored Access queries. Then bind parameters using [QueryDefs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydef-object-dao) in VBA for cleaner, readable, and maintainable code.

Note: the two update queries can be combined into one. Also, the table alias, *t*, is used. When using Query Design, Access will not allow you to save queries with syntax error. Below assumes parameter will be a string/text value.

**SQL**

Update Query

```sql
PARAMETERS idparam TEXT(255);
UPDATE tbl_InterfaceLog t
   SET t.[LastUpdated] = Date(),
       t.[LastUpdatedBy] = Username()
WHERE [CorrectedMedEdID] = idparam;
```

Append Query

```sql
PARAMETERS idparam TEXT(255);
INSERT INTO tbl_AuditLog ([Status], [Comments], [Owner], [corrected med ed ID], 
                          [Upload File Name], [Submission Method], AirfareStatus,
                          GroundStatus, MealsStatus, AccomodationStatus, 
                          AirfareComment, GroundComment, MealsComment, 
                          AccommodationComment, Coordinator, SupportRequested, 
                          LastUpdated, Reviewed, ReviewerComment, RequiredChange, 
                          EventDate, ProductsMatch, SubmissionMethod, 
                          TravelDestination, LastUpdatedBy)

SELECT t.Status, t.Comments, t.Owner, t.[corrected med ed ID], t.[Upload File Name],
       t.[Submission Method], t.AirfareStatus, t.GroundStatus, t.MealsStatus, 
       t.AccomodationStatus, t.AirfareComment, t.GroundComment, t.MealsComment, 
       t.AccommodationComment, t.Coordinator, t.SupportRequested, t.LastUpdated, 
       t.Reviewed, t.ReviewerComment, t.RequiredChange, t.EventDate, t.ProductsMatch, 
       t.SubmissionMethod, t.TravelDestination, t.LastUpdatedBy
FROM tbl_InterfaceLog t
WHERE t.[CorrectedMedEdID] = idparam;
```

**VBA** *(no concatenation)*

```vb
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    Dim UserName As String
    Dim qdef as QueryDef

    ' UPDATE QUERY 
    Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("myUpdateQuery")        
    qdef!idparam = Me.[Corrected Med Ed ID]             ' BIND PARAM
    qdef.Execute dbFailOnError                          ' EXECUTE QUERY
    Set qdef = Nothing    

    ' APPEND QUERY
    Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("myAppendQuery")        
    qdef!idparam = Me.[Corrected Med Ed ID]             ' BIND PARAM
    qdef.Execute dbFailOnError                          ' EXECUTE QUERY
    Set qdef = Nothing
End Sub
```

Or DRY-er approach:

```vb
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    Dim UserName As String, qry As Variant
    Dim qdef as QueryDef

    ' RUN ACTION QUERIES
    For Each qry in Array("myUpdateQuery", "myAppendQuery")
        Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(qry)  
        qdef!idparam = Me.[Corrected Med Ed ID]         ' BIND PARAM
        qdef.Execute dbFailOnError                      ' EXECUTE QUERY
        Set qdef = Nothing    
    Next qry

    Set qdef = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting a data type conversion error here, Is it because the field is short text and primary key?

Comment: I had waited for your response above and originally had a text field. Simply change `LONG` to `TEXT(255)`.

Comment: I apologize :/ . I am getting "Too few Parameters. Expected 2."

Comment: Run the queries by themselves in Query Design (cancel action on prompt) and find which fields are not recognized if it asks. It should only ask for *idparam*. Can be simple spelling issue.

Comment: I did just that and it brought me to the fields with the typos. I appreciate you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked and researched whether the SQL column names in the database are case-sensitive when delimited? That is, on this table creation. If so, `[corrected med ed ID]` ≠ `[Corrected Med Ed ID]`

You can try and fix Case and see if it works.